# Maven dependency plugin does not rebuild dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I have multi-module project with structure like:

```
my-project
 - moduleA
 - moduleB
 - moduleC
```

pom.xml for moduleA configured like:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>withArtifacts</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>

                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.ekiryuhin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>moduleB</artifactId>
                            <version>${project.version}</version>
                        </dependency>

                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.ekiryuhin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>moduleC</artifactId>
                            <version>${project.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>

                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <includeArtifactIds>
                                    moduleB,moduleC
                                </includeArtifactIds>
                                <outputDirectory>
                                    ${project.build.directory}/lib
                                </outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then:

1. Add some code in classes inside `moduleB` and `moduleC`.
2. `cd` to `my-project/moduleA`.
3. Run `mvn clean install -PwithArtifacts -DskipTests -am`

And finally I have jar files in `${project.build.directory}/lib` but they do not contain my edits from (1).

Why maven may do not rebuild dependencies before copy?

**UPD:**

pom.xml from moduleB:

Comment: Please show the pom files...Why are you using maven-dependency-plugin ? Better go with maven-shade-plugin/maven-assembly-plugin ...?

Comment: @khmarbaise I don't know how to do the same with another plugin

Comment: So you want to build an executable jar file?

Comment: I want to rebuild and copy dependencies to specified path

Comment: So you don't want do built an executable jar. Sorry this is what I don't understand? Why a specified path? Do you like to deploy to a Server? Or what? Sorry but I don't understand your request? Can you elaborate more in detail what you like to do?

Comment: I want to build module `moduleA` and copy `moduleB` and `moduleC` jar files to `${project.build.directory}/lib`. Than code in `moduleA` should deploy those jar files to server for using as Solr libs.

Comment: So you want to misuse a build tool for deployment... Better would be to package the needed parts via maven-shade/assembly and let the deployment being done by the right tools (ansible, ssh, chef, puppet, etc. or even a Jenkins etc.)...

Comment: This build run by jenkins and I don't try to use maven instead deployment tool. I just try to build few not executable jar.

Comment: Create the needed things via maven-assembly/maven-shade and deploy them to repository manager afterwards you can deploy them with other tools...as I already mentioned. Why not assembly/shade?

Answer (score 1):

You need build *all* the modules for that. Go the main project `my-project` and call `mvn clean install`. You also need to make sure that moduleA depends on moduleB and moduleC so that the build order will be correct.

Comment: I thought if I build `moduleA` with `-am` flag modules that depended by `moduleA` will be rebuilt.

Comment: Yes, but only if run this on `my-project`. So if you run (on `my-project`) something like `mvn clean install -pl moduleA -am`, this should work (if `moduleA` and `moduleB` are dependencies)

Comment: I tried to run build on `my-project` (`clean install -pl=com.ekiryuhin:module1 -am`) and this did not work. Also I checked that `moduleB` and `moduleC` are dependencies of  `moduleA`.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. Try to use it exactly as I wrote it.